# getting Firebase Cloud Storage metadata

Tags: java, rest, firebase, google-cloud-storage

After issuing the following Java REST GET request, I recieve a response that does not look like the Resource Representations given on the documentation page at: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects#resource

Can somebody see what I am doing wrong?

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://www.googleapis.com/storage/" +
"v1/b/fir-sqlite-6d578.appspot.com/o/" +
"FwhnuuaipmSrOU2lhPw8JqRHddw2%2F-L7-dxfPvKAQhrTGCmFu%2F" +
"Catalina_Island.PNG");
```

I process the response as follows.

```
// get the response entity
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

// read from an inputstream
InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
final int MAX_BUF_LEN = 2048;
char[] aChar = new char[MAX_BUF_LEN];
Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
int n;
while ((n = reader.read(aChar)) != -1) {
    System.out.print(aChar);
}
```

The response I get is the following. (I edited the response to remove a lot of redundant white space)

```
{
"kind": "storage#object",
"id": "fir-sqlite-6d578.appspot.com/FwhnuuaipmSrOU2lhPw8JqRHddw2/-L7-dxfPvKAQhrTGCmFu/Catalina_Island.PNG/1520429424730372",
"selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/fir-sqlite-6d578.appspot.com/o/FwhnuuaipmSrOU2lhPw8JqRHddw2%2F-L7-dxfPvKAQhrTGCmFu%2FCatalina_Island.PNG",
"name": "FwhnuuaipmSrOU2lhPw8JqRHddw2/-L7-dxfPvKAQhrTGCmFu/Catalina_Island.PNG",
"bucket": "fir-sqlite-6d578.appspot.com",
"generation": "1520429424730372",
"metageneration": "1",
"contentType": "image/png",
"timeCreated": "2018-03-07T13:30:24.580Z",
"updated": "2018-03-07T13:30:24.580Z",
"storageClass": "STANDARD",
"timeStorageClassUpdated": "2018-03-07T13:30:24.580Z",
"size": "447728",
"md5Hash": "H2tBdu/ZFxZHuLbwReLV5g==",
"mediaLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/fir-sqlite-6d578.appspot.com/o/FwhnuuaipmSrOU2lhPw8JqRHddw2%2F-L7-dxfPvKAQhrTGCmFu%2FCatalina_Island.PNG?generation=1520429424730372&alt=media",
"contentDisposition": "inline; filename*=utf-8''Catalina_Island.PNG",
"metadata": {
"firebaseStorageDownloadTokens": "4a674342-60fd-4ef1-943f-49ce1bcaa49a"
},
"crc32c": "S+0AwA==",
"etag": "CITCkf6o2tkCEAE="
}
PvKAQhrTGCmFu/Catalina_Island.PNG",
    "bucket": "fir-sqlite-6d578.appspot.com",
    "generation": "1520429424730372",
    "metageneration": "1",
    "contentType": "image/png",
    "timeCreated": "2018-03-07T13:30:24.580Z",
    "updated": "2018-03-07T13:30:24.580Z",
    "storageClass": "STANDARD",
    "timeStorageClassUpdated": "2018-03-07T13:30:24.580Z",
    "size": "447728",
    "md5Hash": "H2tBdu/ZFxZHuLbwReLV5g==",
    "mediaLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/
```

Comment: Do you mean that the response is a malformed JSON (as you presented it)? Otherwise, the fields you get seem to match what is documented here https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects#resource.